# android WebView goes on the browser

Tags: android, webview

hi guys i have a listView and when you click on each an intent will start intent work is so simple show you the url of item but when i click on item go straight to the browser and show the currect url there
this is my Adapter Click Code

```
urlLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url =twitch.getUrl();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,TwitchWebView.class);
            intent.putExtra("url",url);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and this is webview activity code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitch_web_view);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.twitch_web_view);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = bundle.getString("url");
    if (url!= null){
        Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        wv.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

i want to show me the url on this webView (url about Twitch.tv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }
        });
```

Comment: worked perfectly thanks a lot

Comment: need 2 more minutes to accept the answer

Comment: Great! please upvote.I am here for you

Comment: i have another question should i do extra works because the stream cant play but in browser play without problems

Comment: WebSettings webSetting = wv.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);

Comment: webView (http://s9.picofile.com/file/8316674318/twitch.jpg) on browser (http://s9.picofile.com/file/8316674442/broswer.jpg)

Comment: Let me know if it works or not? also provide me stream url

Comment: now the playbutton is here but when you click Stuck at loading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163128/discussion-between-sadegh-and-pankaj-kant-patel).